# MySQL-Linux error when attempting to stop its service

Tags: mysql, linux

This is the message I got when I was trying to stop a MySQL server on my machine:

```
MySQL manager or server PID file could not be found
```

The command I executed:

```
service mysql stop
```

or

```
/etc/init.d/mysqld stop
```

I also attempted to start the MySQL server, but I got the following error

```
Starting MySQL.Manager of pid-file quit without updating file
```

I cannot access MySQL database.

A few points to address:

1. I have the my.cnf file under /etc/my.cnf
2. `ps -ef |grep mysql` does not display any processes
3. `/var/run/mysqld/` is empty (no `mysql.pid` file)
4. `/tmp/mysql.sock` does not exist

I read the file `/var/log/mysqld.log` and it seemed that mysql was trying to do some crash recovery. There could be a shutdown yesterday but it was out of my control. I just want to get the database back. Can any expert help me? I have the sudo account of this machine but I would not reboot this machine unless it is the last option because it is a server used by other people.

Comment: +1 for awesome explanation. Try repairing all the tables?

Comment: We finally choose to reboot the system. The problem was caused by somebody who made a large query which could run forever. He did not want to wait so he pressed the "Ctrl+c", but he did not realized that the disk was already full. We lost some data, indeed.

Comment: If that is your answer, please add it as an answer and mark it as answered.

Comment: "If that is your answer, please add it as an answer and mark it as answered." Seconded.

Comment: **service mysql stop** won't work, you need to run **service mysqld start/stop** or whatever in order to interact we the mysql service.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error and after searching the first 4 pages of google and trying everything suggested (repairing tables, moving my.cnf, clearing locks, rebooting etc) nothing worked. It turned out that it was because I had manually cleared some old binary logs (binary.00001, binary.00002 etc) but i hadn't updated the binary.index file to match. I deleted the appropriate lines from binary.index and it just worked.